# What is the fastest NoSQL database that meets these requirements?

Tags: database, apache, embedded, nosql, bsd

I want a fastest `nosql` database with following requirement

- It must be licensed under Apache or BSD or other but must not GPL
- It must support java
- It should work in embedded mode
- Should provide High Performance Search (for char search within word)
- Should provide Compression option.

Please suggest if you know any db that fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to answer this question, because "I want the fastest database" isn't specific enough to give you an answer.

Databases can be "fast" in some ways and slow in others. For example, MongoDB has extremely fast read/write performance, but it can't really do joins, and your data isn't always guaranteed to be written. Likewise, MySQL is wretched for full-text search, but it offers reasonable levels of power across many metrics.

Based on your requirement that it be embeddable, you should probably look at `sqlite`, which is public-domain, embeddable, has Java bindings, supports full-text search with extensions, and can be compressed with extensions. (It's not NoSQL, but you also didn't mention why you really need that, and I suspect a lot of people just pick it because it sounds cool.)

Comment: am developing a bookmark app where i store millions of links and their titles and i want to implement a pattern searching similar to the Firefox awesome bar so i thought nosql is better. Any suggestions...

Comment: That's not a particularly compelling use case for NoSQL. (In fact, Firefox's own bookmarks/awesomebar has used sqlite for data storage.)

Answer (score 0):

> am developing a bookmark app where i store millions of links and their
>   titles and i want to implement a pattern searching similar to the
>   Firefox awesome bar so i thought nosql is better. Any suggestions.

Maybe off the main topic but...

I built a bookmarking app for myself (after I lost access to delicious for a while -- fortunately I'd done a recent export and had my data) using Ruby on Rails and SQLite. The **meta-search** gem gives pretty good searching capabilities and can be used to sort the output results. It's very easy to implement and in a database of 800+ bookmarks returns results in about a second  (perceived time, I've never bothered to benchmark it).  There's an excellent tutorial at railscasts.com (episode 251).

Of course, as a fan of Ruby on Rails, I may be biased but it's quick to build and provides a RESTful interface out of the box which can return XML if you'd prefer to consume it in a Java app to native display.